# Fast inverse square root trick

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science

I found what appears to be an intriguing method for calculating $$\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$$ extremely fast on [this website,](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-quakes-fast-inverse-square-root/) with more [explanation here.](http://www.lomont.org/Math/Papers/2003/InvSqrt.pdf)

However, the computer-science lingo and "floating"-stuffs left me in the dark as to how it works. I don't actually know what the algorithm is because I can't read C code, so could someone

1. Explain the algorithm in mathematical terms
2. Explain why it works

(I got the impression that it's using Newton's method with a clever choice of first guess.)

---

For the convenience of the readers I (the user String) allowed myself to include the C++ code:

```
float InvSqrt(float x)
      {
      float xhalf = 0.5f*x; // store 0.5x since x will be changed
      int i = *(int*)&x; // convert to binary integer
      i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1); // the smart trick
      x = *(float*)&i; // convert binary back to decimal
      x = x*(1.5f-xhalf*x*x); // Newton-Raphson step
      return x;
      }
```

Comment: That is a lovely trick, but it is intrinsically tied to the bit format for floats, so it is more related to computer science than mathematics.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is there nothing relevant to mathematics? (As in, is the only mathematics used a simple application of Newton's method, and everything else is computer science tricks?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, your description of the general aim of the algorithm is correct! It IS indeed Newton-Raphson's method with a clever *initial guess*. I will only comment on arriving at the clever guess.

### Conversion to binary

Trying to phrase it in mostly mathematical terms, the computer takes a decimal number $x\in[1\cdot 2^{-127},2\cdot 2^{128})$ and calculates a piecewise linear approximation to the base $2$ logarithm by finding $q\in[0,1)$ and an integer $e\in[-127,128]$ such that
$$
x=(1+q)\cdot 2^e
$$
This expression depends linearly on $q$ and exponentially on $e$ and we have the piecewise linear approximation
$$
\log_2(x)\approx e+q=\underbrace{\lfloor \log_2(x)\rfloor}_e+\underbrace{x/2^{\lfloor \log_2(x)\rfloor}-1}_q
$$
Here is a diagram of the situation with $\log_2(x)$ as the blue curve and $e+q$ as the red polygon:
[image: Approximation of log_2]

To store this information, the computer transforms it into a positive integer
$$
i=\lfloor(e+127+q)\cdot 2^{23}\rfloor
$$
where the integer part of $(e+127+q)$ is the non-negative $(e+127)\in[0,255]$. Note that the floor function used here, which is essentially truncating the number $(1+q)$ after $23$ binary digits of $q$, leads to a loss of precision of at most $2^{-23}\approx 0.000000119$. This is not much and we will disregard it in the following for a cleaner rendering.

### Binary digit shifting

The code $\texttt{(i>>1)}$ takes the integer $\texttt{i}$ and shifts its binary digits to the right, dropping the last digit. So with $\texttt{i=1010}$ or $\texttt{i=1011}$ we have $\texttt{(i>>1)=101}$. In effect we have
$$
\texttt{(i>>1)}=\lfloor i/2\rfloor
$$
Again the floor function has relatively little effect so we will disregard it.

### The "magic" number

You can check with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0x5f3759df/2%5E23) that recognizing $\texttt{0x5f3759df}$ as hexidecimal we have
$$
\begin{align}
\texttt{0x5f3759df}&=1597463007 \\
&= 190.43243014812469482421875\cdot 2^{23}
\end{align}
$$
For brevity let us just write $190.43243$. Thus the code line $\texttt{i=0x5f3759df-(i>>1)}$ changes $i$ to the new value
$$
\begin{align}
i_*&= 190.43243\cdot 2^{23}-i/2 \\
&=[190.43243-(e+127+q)/2]\cdot 2^{23} \\
&=[126.93243-(e+q)/2]\cdot 2^{23} \\
&\approx(127+\log_2(1/\sqrt x))\cdot 2^{23}
\end{align}
$$
So when the integer $i_*$ above is transformed backwards via the piecewise linear approximation into a decimal number we have
$$
\begin{align}
x_*&=\left(1+\text{frac}(126.93243-(e+q)/2)\right)\cdot 2^{\lfloor 126.93243-(e+q)/2\rfloor-127}\\
&\approx [1+\text{frac}(126.93243+log_2(1/\sqrt x))]\cdot 2^{\lfloor\log_2(1/\sqrt x)\rfloor} \\
&\approx 2^{\log_2(1/\sqrt x)} \\
&=1/\sqrt x
\end{align}
$$

### Why not 190.5?

This is simply to balance the error function of the expression above to minimize the errors. With 190.5 we would have had $127$ instead of $126.93243$ but due to the linear approximations involved this would have lead to skewed errors so that some numbers $x$ would lead to an almost perfect $x_*=1/\sqrt x$ whereas other numbers $x$ would work relatively bad compared to that. Shifting by $190.5-190.43243=0.06757$ apparantly does the trick of balancing errors better.

In both the article you linked to and in a more [recent article](http://www.daxia.com/bibis/upload/406Fast_Inverse_Square_Root.pdf) by a different author some work has been done deriving better constants than $190.43243$. I have not carefully read the sections about that in either of the articles, though.

I hope this clarifies the general principle of the algorithm without going into too much nor too little detail regarding the aim of your question.

Comment: In the practical implementation, I am sure the computer does something different than finding the approximation to $\log_2(x)$ adding $127$ and multiplying it by $2^{23}$. There will be an efficient algorithm giving the same final result. Also note how efficient the shift operation $\texttt{(i>>1)}$ is for dividing a binary number by $2$. Just like we all know how to quickly divide by $10$ in our decimal representation by shifting the point. That fits cleverly into the current purpose of finding inverse square roots quickly!