# Better algorithm to find numerical value of one over squareroot

Tags: numerical-methods, radicals, newton-raphson

**Description:** To find the value of $1/\sqrt{a}$, basically we find the root $x^{\star}$ of the function $f(x)$

$$
f(x) = x^2 - \dfrac{1}{a}
$$

One of the ways to find it is by using Newton's method and iterating from an initial value $x_0$.

$$
x_{k+1} = x_{k} - \dfrac{f(x_{k})}{f'(x_k)} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(x_k + \dfrac{1}{ax_k}\right)
$$
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty}x_{k} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}
$$

This is known as Newton's method which has quadratic convergence, for some positive constant $M$:

$$
\left|x_{k+1} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right| \le M \cdot \left|x_{k} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right|^2
$$

**Question:** Is there a better numerical method, which convergence is higher than Newton's method, to find $x^{\star} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$?

**EDIT:** I thought about using Taylor expansion until second order, once Newton's method is made using first-order expansion:

> $$ f(x) = f(x_k) + (x-x_k) \cdot f'(x_k) + \dfrac{(x-x_k)^2}{2} \cdot f''(x_k) + \dfrac{(x-x_k)^3}{6} \cdot f'''(\varepsilon(x)) $$
>
> And then find the value of $x_{k+1}$ that
>
> $$0 = f(x_k) + (x_{k+1} - x_k) \cdot f'(x_k)+ \dfrac{(x_{k+1}-x_k)^2}{2} \cdot f''(x_k)$$
>
> Using the function $f(x) = x - \dfrac{1}{ax}$ we rewrite
>
> $$x_{k+1}^2 - \left(3+ax_k^2\right) \cdot x_k \cdot x_{k+1} + 3x_k^2 = 0$$
>
> Which solution is
>
> $$x_{k+1} = \dfrac{x_k}{2}\left(3ax_k^2 - \sqrt{\left(3+ax_{k}^2\right)^2 - 12}\right)$$
>
> As there's a square-root, it may be hard to compute and then we make a second-order Taylor approximation around $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ of this square-root:
>
> $$\sqrt{\left(3+ax^2\right)^2 - 12}\approx 6x\sqrt{a} - ax^2 -3$$
>
> Once $\sqrt{a} \approx \dfrac{1}{2}\left(y+\dfrac{a}{y}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{x} + ax\right)$ then
>
> $$\sqrt{\left(3+ax^2\right)^2 - 12}\approx 6x \cdot \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{x} + ax\right) -ax^2 - 3 = 2ax^2$$
> $$\boxed{x_{k+1} = \dfrac{x_k(3-ax_k^2)}{2}}$$
>
> Which is a simple function of polynomials.
>
> But I have no idea about the convergence of using this iteration function.
> Its order would be $3$ cause we used second-order taylor expansion of $f$, but using linear approximations of the square root around $1/\sqrt{a}$ seems it's bellow $3$.
>
> 1. Then, how about other functions like $f=x^4-a^{-2}$ and using the same tricks?

**Motivation:** There's an algorithm known as [Fast Inverse Square Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) (more details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800815/fast-inverse-square-root-trick)) which starts from a good estimative (using logarithm and bit manipulation), but it uses Newton's iteration to refine the value at final step.

Comment: 'Faster' is relative to the beginning and end times. See for example <a href='https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965913002930#br000005'>here</a>.   This rapidly can become a computer science question rather than a math question.

Comment: The fast inverse square root algorithm exploits how floating point numbers are stored in a computer. As such it is not a mathematical algorithm - if it were, it would work equally well (by count of operations) with any means of storing numbers. Instead, it requires a specific storage format to even work.

Comment: @Narlin Thank you. By saying faster I meant it has a higher convergence order, just like you sent the link, which applies to get a $1+\sqrt{2}\approx 2.4$ order instead of $2$ (Newton).

Comment: If you apply Newton's method to $f(x) = x^{-2} - a$ you get $x \to \frac{(3 - a x^2)x}{2}$ which doesn't have general division (division by 2 may be easier for computers).  No higher convergence order though.

Comment: One can derive higher order methods than Newton's, but a quadratic method doubles the number of significant figures each iteration.  The higher order methods will generally require more computation per step, so doing more iterations of Newton is usually competitive.

Comment: You can quadruple the number of correct digits in every step - if you simply declare two  Newton steps as a single step of your algorithm …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Householder's method of order $d$ to solve $f(x) = 0$ gives

$$x \to H_d(x) = x + d \frac {\left(1/f\right)^{(d-1)}(x)}{\left(1/f\right)^{(d)}(x)}$$

with rate of convergence $d + 1$.

Using the (wx)Maxima computer algebra system, for

$$f(x) = x^{-2} - a$$

I get

$$\begin{aligned}
H_1(x) &= \frac{(3 - a x^2)x}{2} \\
H_2(x) &= \frac{(3 + a x^2)x}{3 a x^2 + 1} \\
H_3(x) &= \frac{a^2x^4 + 6ax^2 + 1}{4ax(ax^2+1)} \\
H_4(x) &= \frac{x(a^2x^4 + 10ax^2 + 5)}{5a^2x^4 + 10ax^2 + 1} \\
\end{aligned}$$

Suppose the target precision is $N$ accurate digits.
The last iteration giving $N$ accurate digits needs $N/(d+1)$ accurate digits as input, so there are around $\log_{d+1} N$ iteration steps needed.

Assume the cost of $D$-digit digit multiplication (and hence division) is given by some function $M(D)$ (for example $M(D) = D^{\log_2 3}$ when using Karatsuba algorithm), and assume that multiplication and division by small integers, and addition and subtraction of $D$-digit numbers, are insignificant in comparison.  Then the cost depends on whether the number of digits of $a$ is small or large.  Many calculations can be reused/shared to reduce number of multiplications.

For small $a$:

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{cost}(H_1) = 2 (M(N/1) + M(N/2) + M(N/4) + \cdots + M(1))  &< \frac{2}{\log 2} M(N) \log(N) \\
\operatorname{cost}(H_2) = 3 (M(N/1) + M(N/3) + M(N/9) + \cdots + M(1)) &< \frac{3}{\log 3} M(N)\log(N) \\
\operatorname{cost}(H_3) = 4 (M(N/1) + M(N/4) + M(N/16) + \cdots + M(1)) &< \frac{4}{\log 4} M(N) \log(N) \\
\operatorname{cost}(H_4) = 4 (M(N/1) + M(N/5) + M(N/25) + \cdots + M(1)) &< \frac{4}{\log 5} M(N) \log(N) \\
\end{aligned}$$

showing that higher orders improve overall cost, at least when $N$ is large enough that additions etc really are insignificant.

For $a$ with $N$ digits:

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{cost}(H_1) = 3 (M(N/1) + M(N/2) + M(N/4) + \cdots + M(1))  &< \frac{3}{\log 2} M(N) \log(N) \\
\operatorname{cost}(H_2) = 4 (M(N/1) + M(N/3) + M(N/9) + \cdots + M(1)) &< \frac{4}{\log 3} M(N) \log(N) \\
\operatorname{cost}(H_3) = 5 (M(N/1) + M(N/4) + M(N/16) + \cdots + M(1)) &< \frac{5}{\log 4} M(N) \log(N) \\
\operatorname{cost}(H_4) = 5 (M(N/1) + M(N/5) + M(N/25) + \cdots + M(1)) &< \frac{5}{\log 5} M(N) \log(N) \\
\end{aligned}$$

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder%27s_method

(wx)Maxima source code:

```
f(x) := x^(-2) - a;
H(d, x) := factor(ratsimp(x + d * (diff(1/f(x), x, d - 1)) / (diff(1/f(x), x, d))));
H(1, x);
H(2, x);
H(3, x);
```